# WSO2 ESB How to deliver the message of the Custom Mediator in EndPoint

Tags: wso2, mediator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Good day!

I only recently began to study the ESB bus. I need to convert the incoming SOAP message in the HTTP request with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I have created a Proxy Service, Custom Mediator 1 in Java, transformed message, how do I pass it to the endpoint and get the answer in Custom Mediator 2?

In the picture I have drawn an example of how to transform the message.

[image]

Comment: no, this is my first project

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write custom mediators, you can transform SOAP to rest calls, sample with a rest service waiting for 2 parameters like

> param1=value1&param2=value2

```
<!-- prepare data for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter message formatter -->
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format> 
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
            <soapenv:Body> 
                <root> 
                    <param1>$1</param1> 
                    <param2>$2</param2> 
                </root> 
            </soapenv:Body> 
        </soapenv:Envelope> 
    </format> 
    <args> 
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/node1/node11/text()"/> 
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/node1/node12/text()"/> 
   </args> 
</payloadFactory>  

<!-- set output format -->

<property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/> 
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/> 

<!-- call the REST endpoint with synch call : response is received in this sequence -->

<call> 
   <endpoint key="conf:endpoints/MyServiceEndpoint.xml"/> 
</call> 

<!-- the response is here, transform it has needed -->
<xslt key="myxsl"/>

<!-- send this response to the client -->
<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>  
<!-- or test/xml and in this case, don't forget to specify a SOAP Action, below, a sample to specify a blank soapAction : -->
<header name="Action" value="&quot;&quot;"/>
<send/>
```

Sample endpoint conf (with this sample, you need to define a property uri.var.ServiceURL in your sequence) :

```
<endpoint>
  <http method="POST" uri-template="{uri.var.ServiceURL}/Path/2011-10-01"/>
</endpoint>
```

But if you really need your custom mediators, just replace payloadFactory and xslt mediators with them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I still have to write custom mediator, just a very complex transformation messages
I will give an example how should I transform the message

1. SOAP message in my Proxy Service, send in custrom mediator

> ```
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>   <soap:Body>
>     <AddPay xmlns="http://MyTestService">
>       <!--input dynamic data-->
>       <fields>
>         <Items>
>           <Data>
>             <Name>Field1</Name>
>             <Value>11</Value>
>           </Data>
>           <Data>
>             <Name>Field2</Name>
>             <Value>22</Value>
>           </Data>
>         </Items>
>       </fields>
>     </AddPay>
>   </soap:Body>
> </soap:Envelope>
> ```

2. The result of the transformation of the mediator

> ```
> 0000035401SM000000970000009700000121
> api99             00000990
>                   00000000
> BEGIN     // <!--input dynamic data-->
> FIELD1=11 // Soap data
> FIELD2=22 // Soap data
> END
>
> BEGIN SIGNATURE
> iQBRAwkBAAAD3j2r2NwBAeevAf4nvAG4rGAyAePHkyVKTt7wffzURhOckd3ctgmG
> yQkKWkXh3CLpsbrExsllVUBlO6ih8qHozk2uttXApzHXQXoO
> =+pch
> END SIGNATURE
> ```

3. Request to the HTTP Server

> ```
> POST /cgi-bin/es/es_pay_check.cgi HTTP/1.0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 498
> inputmessage=0000035401SM000000970000009700000121%0D%0Aapi99+
> +++++++++++00000990%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++00000000%0ABEGIN%0D%
> 0FIELD1%11%0FIELD2%220AEND%0D%0ABEGIN+SIGNATURE%0AiQBRAwkBAABCiUs
> 00dQBATG5AgDHdZ6RYHykL46QBaAvnHYaY4p0pDjgjO4K1Iyj%0D%0AfSBSvCRpS%2
> F0EYO9NspuyLeANEQQkkGE%2F37gUxiPqzAgStXjpsAHH%0D%0A%3DvSgb%0AEND+
> SIGNATURE
> ```

4. The response from the HTTP Server, pass in custrom mediator to transform into SOAP

> ```
> 0000030301SM000000460000004600000121
> 0J0005            00064182
>                   00000000
> BEGIN
> DATE=04.10.2014 12:34:12
> ERROR=0
> ERRMSG=
> FIELD3=33
> FIELD4=44
> FIELD5=55
> END
> BEGIN SIGNATURE
> iQBRAwkBAAD6tj1BJ10BAYKxAfsHlQsEFnO2k6ry++W8O8AiJuv4gT+ZVCfZHsKk
> c0CbZpP/W3vkljG3xNzMLiqjbwkNuIdwR9Dq7gHmH+ZQMhbT
> =LOnP
> END SIGNATURE
> ```

5. The result in the Proxy service

> ```
> <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <s:Body>
>     <AddPayResponse xmlns="http://MyTestService">
>       <AddPayResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>         <Data>
>           <Items>
>             <!--output dynamic data-->
>             <Data>
>               <Name>Field3</Name>
>               <Value>33</Value>
>             </Data>
>             <Data>
>               <Name>Field4</Name>
>               <Value>44</Value>
>             </Data>
>             <Data>
>               <Name>Field5</Name>
>               <Value>55</Value>
>             </Data>
>           </Items>
>         </Data>
>         <ErrCode>0</ErrCode>
>         <ErrMsg>Ok</ErrMsg>
>       </AddPayResult>
>     </AddPayResponse>
>   </s:Body>
> </s:Envelope>
> ```